# Auto increment Id value increased by 1 after insert trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

I have 3 tables as below:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_dummy` (
    `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `user_email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

CREATE TABLE `user_role` (
    `user_role_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_role_name` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_role_id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

CREATE TABLE `user` (
    `user_seq` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `user_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `user_email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `user_role_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_seq`),
    INDEX `FKh2wc2dtfdo8maylne7mgubowq` (`user_role_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FKh2wc2dtfdo8maylne7mgubowq` FOREIGN KEY (`user_role_id`) REFERENCES `user_role` (`user_role_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

I have created after insert trigger on user table. 
i.e., when I insert 1 record into user_dummy table, it will insert records into table user table with all mappings of user_role.

trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `user_dummy_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `user_dummy` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    INSERT INTO user(user_id, user_name, user_email, user_role_id)
    SELECT NEW.user_id, NEW.user_name, NEW.user_email, user_role_id 
    FROM user_role;

END
```

Above trigger is able to insert records into user table but the auto_increment value is incremented by 1 after each user_role record.

[image][image] 
[image]

If you observe user_seq 3 is missing. And after inserting 4 records, auto_increment value set by trigger as 7.

[image]

How to fix this ?

Comment: Why does having a completely continuous auto increment sequence matter to you?  The contract of an auto increment column only requires that the values are unique, and ever increasing (but not necessarily continuous).

Comment: Also, from normalization perspective, you should rather have a junction table between user and user_role; instead of storing multiple user_role and user combination rows in a single table.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I know that, Just for my question, i took that example. I cant share my actual structure.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I agree with you but I would like to know why its behaving like that.

Answer (score 0):

**Just an alternative**: Better you could use the count function to count the total existing records and then increase it by one and assign according as. If you are interested to preserve the insertion sequence.

Comment: That sounds like a way a **race conditation** could happening right there.. unless you do it in one query.. `INSERT INTO table (<columns>) SELECT COUNT(*), <columns> FROM table ...`

Comment: I just provided an alternative. As per his requirement. I agree with you buddy.